# Basement Bath Drain/Vent Help

Tags: bathroom, basement, drain-waste-vent

I'm finishing my basement, and adding a bath in the process. I'm hoping to get some help with drain/vent questions. The current stack is right in the middle of where the new shower will be. I'm moving it against a wall just a few feet away. I'm just a little confused on how I should vent the bath, and where the best place to connect the new stack and the shower line into the system. Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYjr5.jpg)

The black lines are 3", blue are 2" and green are vent

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that toilet in top left corner will be going away

Comment: Need more info.  How are you moving the main stack, are you cutting into the concrete ?   How/ where are the new drains tying into the main stack ?  Are you building out a wood framed wall against the concrete wall to house the new plumbing ?  More info is needed.

Comment: Good questions...yes the floor will be broken up and the stack moved into a framed out wall behind the shower.

One of my questions is should the new bathroom drains connect before or after the main stack? The 3" line black line running through the new bath is lined up with where the current line exits the house, so I will just tie into it a little beyond the frame of the picture.

Comment: Please put all new information in the question body. If your would-be volunteers don't find it up there they may move on without responding.

Comment: if you're putting a kink in the stack that'll have tricky venting requirements itself, or are you moving the whole stack?